# What Rate of Push Notifications Triggers TooManyRequests Error?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Pretty simple...

For example, If I send 5 in a loop, will this trigger failure?

Just wondering if anyone with experience can ballpark this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no specific limit in the docs ([Communicating with APNs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingwithAPNs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH11-SW1)).

> There are no caps or batch size limits for using APNs. The iOS 6.1 press release stated that APNs has sent over 4 trillion push notifications since it was established. It was announced at WWDC 2012 that APNs is sending 7 billion notifications daily.
>
> If you're seeing throughput lower than 9,000 notifications per second, your server might benefit from improved error handling logic.

Error 429 indicates `The server received too many requests for the same device token`. If you are having issues, you might want to check [Technical Note TN2265 - Troubleshooting Push Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2265/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010376-CH1-TNTAG44)